# How to format the time in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i  want to know how to convert  the time into  "08:14PM 05 Jan 2013" format using javascript/jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: `var date = new Date();`
`h = date.getHours();`
`m = date.getMinutes();`

i'm stucked at getting 3 letter short month

Comment: The most efficient way is `objectOfNames[ monthNumber ]`, where you've pre-written the name you want for each month as properties of the _Object_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Month as a 3-letter string use

```
date.toDateString().split(' ')[1];
```